# Install python-igraph with anaconda2 pip, no C core found. Linux Fedora 24

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, fedora, igraph

I want to install igraph for python 2.7.12 from Anaconda 4.1.1 I have Fedora 24. As suggested (https://anaconda.org/pypi/python-igraph) I used this command line:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple python-igraph
```

The output included these lines:

[...]

```
Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.
  We will now try to download and compile the C core from scratch.
  Version number of the C core: 0.7
  We will also try: 0.7.0

  Downloading igraph-0.7.0.tar.gz... 100.00%
  Extracting igraph-0.7.0.tar.gz...
  Configuring igraph...
  checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
  checking whether build environment is sane... yes
  checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
  checking for gawk... gawk
  checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
  checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
  checking for suffix of executables...
  checking whether we are cross compiling... no
  checking for suffix of object files... o
  checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
  checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
  checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
  checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
  checking for style of include used by make... GNU
  checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
  checking for g++... no
  checking for c++... no
  checking for gpp... no
  checking for aCC... no
  checking for CC... no
  checking for cxx... no
  checking for cc++... no
  checking for cl.exe... no
  checking for FCC... no
  checking for KCC... no
  checking for RCC... no
  checking for xlC_r... no
  checking for xlC... no
  checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
  checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
  checking dependency style of g++... none
  configure: error: no C++ compiler found or it cannot create executables
  Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.
```

[...]

```
In file included from src/vertexseqobject.c:26:0:
    src/attributes.h:27:31: fatal error: igraph_attributes.h: No such file or directory
     #include <igraph_attributes.h>
                                   ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/ritamaria/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;_

_file__='/tmp/pip-build-aKLm3d/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-32PKAO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-aKLm3d/python-igraph/
```

However when I check to see if I have gcc I get:

```
dnf install gcc
Last metadata expiration check: 1:16:49 ago on Fri Jul 15 09:02:56 2016.
Package gcc-6.1.1-3.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

From the igraph webpage says:

> if the C core is not installed or is installed in a location that
>   cannot be detected using pkg-config, pip will attempt to download a
>   matching version of the C core and compile it together with the Python
>   interface.

So I guess pip tried to download the C core but couldn't/didn't work.

How can I install python-igraph properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current state is that you have to compile igraph yourself (be aware that the master branch of igraph does not currently compile in msvc: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/pull/951) and set some lines in setup.py to the right dirs/files to get it working. Unless it works better, I would simply go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph and install the wheel from there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora 24 ...

> checking for g++... no

Install g++ : # `dnf install gcc-c++`

The igraph libraries, igraph_attributes.h, etc. etc. headers.h : # `dnf install igraph-devel` (You get version **0.7.1** ).

The python files :

```
# pip install --upgrade pip
# pip install igraph
```

Comment: Install g++ : # dnf install gcc-c++ worked was enough. Thanks!